# Как убрать лишнее поле в объекте?

Tags: json, angularjs, typescript, angular4

Получаю объект запросом `GET` вида `{'id': 123, 'title': 'name123',...}` (класс1). Нужно получить объект вида `{'title': 'name123',...}` (класс2), т.е. убрать поле `"id"`. Как можно преобразовать один объект в другой? `класс2 item2 = <класс1> item1`, `класс2 item2 = item1 as класс2` не убирают поле, хотя в `класс2` оно в принципе отсутствует.

Answer (score 0):

Классы не имеют механизмов, которые Вы от них ожидаете. Есть подозрение, что Вы используете классы там, где лучше подходит интерфейс тайпскрипта. Я бы на вашем месте написал функцию-трансформатор для преобразования данных

```
interface ReceivedData {
  id: string;
  title: string;
}

interface OutData {
  title: string;
}

const transform: OutData = (input: ReceivedData) => {
  const { id, ...rest } = input;
  return { ...rest };
}

const received: ReceivedData = GET_FROM_URL();

console.log(transform(received));
```

Comment: Конструкция `{ ...rest }` не имеет смысла, проще сразу `rest` возвращать.

Comment: согласен, это для наглядности